# Is it efficient to use plpgsql functions only to validate identifiers and values?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sql-injection

Will my queries be safe from SQL injections if I use `plpgsql` functions only to validate identifiers and values, instead of executing queries.

Here are the example functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_identifier(identi TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN quote_ident(identi);
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_value(val TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN quote_literal(val);
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then i.e. simply use query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE validate_identifier('user_input_identifier') = validate_value('user_input_value');
```

Is this query safe from SQLi, when `user_input_identifier` and `user_input_value` are replaced by actual user input, which might be an SQLi attempt?

Comment: Besides not being safe, the proposed technique doesn't work at all, because the SQL engine will not interpret the result of `validate_identifier()` as an identifier: it's just a string and it won't correlate it to the table in any way. IOW in most cases it will do `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this query safe from SQLi, when user_input_identifier and user_input_value are replaced by actual user input, which might be an SQLi attempt?

The whole sql injection vulnerability is about sanitized input, depending on how you're getting the inputs to the sanitizing function it may not even be safe to use them. In this case, I'll assume you're calling the SELECT statement from a client-library. In such a case, it's

- no safer than if you just called the functions directly.
- less efficient
- still vulnerable to sql injection

The important thing to be safe is that you're binding the values to the input of the function with placeholders.

If your code looks like this,

```
k = sprintf("
  SELECT *
  FROM some_table
  WHERE validate_identifier(%s) = validate_value(%s)
");
```

You're **not** safe. If it looks like this,

```
k = sprintf("
  SELECT *
  FROM some_table
  WHERE quote_ident(%s) = quote_value(%s)
");
```

You're **not** safe. If it looks like this,

```
k = sprintf("
  SELECT *
  FROM some_table
  WHERE \"%s\" = '%s'
");
```

You're **not** safe. And, for all the same reasons. If it looks like this,

```
k = "
  SELECT *
  FROM some_table
  WHERE col = ?
";
k.exec($foo);
```

You're safe. If you don't know `col` at compile time, for instance if you want to safely do `? = ?`, the library will either prefetch the escaped version by running something like this,

```
k = "SELECT quote_ident(?);"
```

Or it'll simply [use a client-side version (which usually binds to `libpq`) thus saving a trip to the server.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-ESCAPE-STRING)

So in answer to your question

> Is it efficient to use plpgsql functions only to validate identifiers and values?

It's *certainly* less efficient, and depending on how you're providing those functions their values, potentially not safe either.

Comment: So this means that if the whole query is executed within a function with the identifier and value passed in as a parameter later on, then I'm safe? Right?

Comment: A query can't be prepared without all the identifiers. That's part of preparation. You can't select from a table if you don't know what table you're selecting from. When a statement is prepared it's know to be valid. From that point you know you're safe with any values. The only question is how are you providing your identifiers and what does your library do. You showed `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE validate_identifier('user_input_identifier') = validate_value('user_input_value')` That's not enough to tell if you're safe. We need to see how it actually looks on the app.

Comment: But the prepared statements give a performance increase, not SQLi protection, am I right?

Comment: No, it gives sql injection protection too because values are known to be values which protects you from sql injection.

Comment: @Qualphey, a bit off topic but prepared statements does not increase performance per se. It makes it possible to reuse statements without recompiling, so it reduces cpu utilization and memory consumption. This is often beneficial for performance, especially for trivial OLTP queries. However, with skew data and/or big complex report queries the pre-compiled statement may fit the current parameters badly, so it may be beneficial performance-wise to recompile the statement every time it is executed.

Comment: @Lennart I don't think that's true, and I've never seen that in practice. Proportionally, query planning time is *way* higher on trivial queries than massive ones. But, i think shaving the query time is a plus on any query. The only time I think it's not advantageous is if they query itself is generated and shortlived.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I have little experience with PostgreSQL, but for Db2 I've seen queries with execution times of 30-40 minutes reduced down to 1-2 minutes when the query is compiled with known parameters instead of parameter markers. Time to compile a query like that is typical << 5 seconds.

Comment: I want to ask additionally: does using `plpgsql` functions provide any extra protection by themselves? Is it okay to use a prepared statement alone when using `SELECT`?

Comment: Using the plpgsql functions provides nothing whatsoever except inefficiency and obfuscation. And a lot of inefficiency as they're not even `IMMUTABLE`